# Unable to access Internet from Azure containers running Windows

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

I use Windows containers in Azure Container Service. My app in the container was able to access the Internet when I started using it. But recently, I found that the newly-created containers are not able to access Internet, even the simplest iis container created with instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-windows-walkthrough

The routing table I got in the container:

```
ifIndex DestinationPrefix                              NextHop                                  RouteMetric PolicyStore
------- -----------------                              -------                                  ----------- -----------
37      255.255.255.255/32                             0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
33      255.255.255.255/32                             0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
32      255.255.255.255/32                             0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
37      224.0.0.0/4                                    0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
33      224.0.0.0/4                                    0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
32      224.0.0.0/4                                    0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
37      192.168.15.255/32                              0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
37      192.168.15.249/32                              0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
37      192.168.0.0/20                                 0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
32      127.255.255.255/32                             0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
32      127.0.0.1/32                                   0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
32      127.0.0.0/8                                    0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
33      10.244.2.255/32                                0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
33      10.244.2.59/32                                 0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
33      10.244.2.0/24                                  0.0.0.0                                          256 ActiveStore
37      0.0.0.0/0                                      192.168.0.1                                      256 ActiveStore
33      0.0.0.0/0                                      10.244.2.1                                       256 ActiveStore
37      ff00::/8                                       ::                                               256 ActiveStore
33      ff00::/8                                       ::                                               256 ActiveStore
32      ff00::/8                                       ::                                               256 ActiveStore
37      fe80::14f3:38ac:8df2:9869/128                  ::                                               256 ActiveStore
33      fe80::1429:dec4:7919:bb65/128                  ::                                               256 ActiveStore
37      fe80::/64                                      ::                                               256 ActiveStore
33      fe80::/64                                      ::                                               256 ActiveStore
32      ::1/128                                        ::                                               256 ActiveStore
```

Kubernetes version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.2", GitCommit:"922a86cfcd65915a9b2f69f3f193b8907d741d9c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-21T08:23:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.6", GitCommit:"7fa1c1756d8bc963f1a389f4a6937dc71f08ada2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-16T18:21:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

How should I do to get Internet access from the container?

Thanks

Comment: can you ping something by its ip address? might be dns issue

Comment: I was not able to ping 8.8.8.8.

Comment: I have the same problem with Azure Container Instances. I can neither ping google.com nor its IP: https://www.screencast.com/t/4HGWwfjl5o